# Online dictionary that lists number of complements for verbs

Tags: discussion

Is there an online dictionary that lists not only whether a verb is intransitive or transitive (e.g. [Merriam-Webster](http://merriam-webster.com) does that), but also how many arguments it binds?

Comment: I think this is usually made clear in the individual definitions. If the verb needs additional phrases, they'll say "with <role>". The number of arguments it binds often differs among senses of the verb.

Comment: Language isn't a matter of simple mathematical rules. It's often very complex: you may be able omit an argument if it is redundant. And a lot of verbs have considerable variety ("paint the house" vs "paint the house red", and even "paint you the house" when you ask an artist to do a painting, etc). Look at the usage examples and use similar words as a guide (this doesn't always work but it's what native speakers do).

Comment: @StuartF it's not for the sake of using English correctly myself, it's for the sake of making it easier to draw syntax trees for English sentences. Especially with prepositional phrases, it can be hard to tell if it's a complement or adjunct, for a certain meaning of a verb.

Comment: Dictionaries don't think in terms of binding arguments. No predicates bind more than 3 arguments. Verbs of transfer (_give, send, tell, ask, pay,_ etc, which have a recipient "indirect object") bind 3 arguments, as do a few verbs of designation (_elect, name, choose_). Transitive predicates bind 2, intransitives 1.